# Series of Nested Radicals

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals

[image]

I can't seem to find a way, squaring the expression would make more terms and would make it harder, I guess there must be something to do with the first and last terms as they sum to 100? or maybe difference of to squares, but i can't solve it.

Comment: Interesting.  Crude estimates quickly tell you which of those answers is correct (all but one are too large).  And a quick numerical calculation confirms the result, but I don't see a cheap algebraic mode of attack.

Comment: Numerical computation strongly supports the conjecture that
 $$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{n+\sqrt{k}}=(1+\sqrt2)\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{n-\sqrt{k}}$$ for $n\geq2$  I don't have any idea how to attack it yet.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Useful fact:**
>
> $$
> \sqrt{a\pm \sqrt{b}}=
> \sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} \pm
> \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}} \tag{1}$$
>
> *Proof:*
>
> \begin{align}
>   RHS^2 &=
>   \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}+\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2} \pm 2
>   \sqrt{\left( \frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2} \right)
>         \left( \frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2} \right)} \\
>   &= a \pm 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2-(a^2-b)}{4}} \\
>   &= a \pm 2\sqrt{\frac{b}{4}} \\
>   &= a \pm \sqrt{b} \\
>   &= LHS^2 \\
>   LHS &= RHS \qquad (a^2 \ge b \ge 0)
> \end{align}

Let

$$S_{\pm}=\sum_{j=1}^{n^2-1} \sqrt{n \pm \sqrt{j}} \tag{2}$$

and reverse the order of summation by taking $\, k=n^2-j$, then

$$S_{\pm}=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1} \sqrt{n \pm \sqrt{n^2-k}} \tag{3}$$

Now by $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$,

$$S_{\pm}=\frac{S_+ \pm S_-}{\sqrt{2}} \implies \frac{S_+}{S_-}=1+\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: sharp answer indeed ! (+1)

Comment: Im really sorry but could you expound on how you got the first eq

Comment: @Supermage1 Well that could be easy.  Just form perfect squares inside the radicals. So just solve $xy=b/4$ and $x+y=a$ to get $x, y$ ans hence the the original radical would equal $\sqrt x+\sqrt y$

Comment: @SuperMage1 I've added a proof for the identity $(1)$ in my answer.  And what *Manthanein* suggested is to find $x$ and $y$ such that $LHS=\sqrt{x+y \pm 2\sqrt{xy} \,}=|\sqrt{x} \pm \sqrt{y} \,|$.