# Calculate $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10+\sqrt{n}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10-\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, fractions

Calculate $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10+\sqrt{n}}}{\sum_{n=1}^{99} \sqrt{10-\sqrt{n}}}$

I have to solve this question for a math class I'm taking, but I'm not making much headway. I tried to let $\sqrt{10+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ in an attempt to make things cancel out, and got that:

$a+b=10$

$4ab=n$

But I don't think it helps me much.

Comment: and in general it seems  $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m^2-1} \sqrt{m+\sqrt{n}}}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{m^2 -1} \sqrt{m-\sqrt{n}}} = 1+\sqrt 2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value of $\frac{\sqrt{10+\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{99}} }{\sqrt{10-\sqrt{1}}+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{10-\sqrt{99}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397863/value-of-frac-sqrt10-sqrt1-sqrt10-sqrt2-cdots-sqrt10-sqrt99)

Comment: @conditionalMethod - it seems I made the same comment there too

Comment: Some other approaches using trigonometry are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3404396/713897).

Comment: While [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404396/simplify-frac-sqrt10-sqrt1-sqrt10-sqrt2-ldots-sqrt10-sqrt99) uses $\frac{ \sqrt{1+\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1+\cos(x)} }{ \sqrt{1-\sin(x)}+\sqrt{1-\cos(x)} }=\sqrt2+1$

Comment: See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2960855/series-of-nested-radicals/2960987#2960987).