# Finding numbers from quotient of sums with roots.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-number-theory

If $$\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{99} (\sqrt{10} + \sqrt{n})}{\sum_{n=1}^{99} (\sqrt{10} - \sqrt{n})} = a + \sqrt{b}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers , find the value of $a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Please help me out on this question , I don't know how to proceed in these type of questions .

Comment: What if we have just one term in the sums, then 2 etc.? Maybe spot a pattern..

Comment: Please have a look at this site, for possible help, if you don't know how to proceed. It is a [popular question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468624/calculate-frac-sum-n-199-sqrt10-sqrtn-sum-n-199-sqrt10-s).